# Noisy .png after rendering Gloss passes

Tags: cycles-render-engine, render-passes, denoise, noise-reduction

I'm using Cycles as my render engine, on the latest version of Blender 3.5.1

In compositor, I used a set of nodes to seperate the highlights (glossy) from the rest in order to save it seperately in a .png file.
[image: Nodes used to output the highlights]

Set alpha Node for transparency, Mix/Math node with add method to get both direct and indirect glossiness, Denoise to get a clean looking result.

Issue : after rendering, I display the result (Viewer node) and it looks perfect, no noise, no issues, and it has transparency
[image: How the highlights look like after rendering]

But when I save it as .png, the image is noisy
[image: Image opened in default windows Photos viewer]

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Please upload your file on [Blend-Exchange](https://blend-exchange.com/), and edit your post to include the download link, so that we can search ourselves.

Answer (score 0):

In your screenshot, you show that you plugged your denoised glossy pass into a viewer node, but not into a Composite.

The Composite is the final output that gets visible as "Render Result" in the image editor and gets saved into files. The viewer node is only a temporary preview for work purposes only.

Plug your denoised glossy into the Composite node, and it should work.

Comment: Hello, My composite node's input is the beauty pass (Image) from Render Layers, even with what you have suggested, it still is noisy after saving. I should specify that all my other results that I have saved as .png from viewer node are not noisy, the only noisy result is the glossy one.